# Ошибка “non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context” при попытке создания объекта вложенного класса

Tags: java, ооп, классы, объекты

Люди, спасите пожалуйста. Написала класс, хочу создать объект, а выдается ошибка “non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context”.
Звездочками выделила проблемные моменты:

```java
package com.company;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.BitSet;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    // **
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BitSet d = new BitSet(128);
        BitSet d1 = new BitSet(128);
        Bits bits = new Bits(128, d, d1 );
    }
    // **

    class Bits
    {
        private BitSet bit1, bit2; //поля экземпляра
        private int size;
        private Random random;

        // **
        public Bits (int size, BitSet b1, BitSet b2) //конструктор
        {
            bit1 = b1;
            bit2 = b2;
        }
        // **
}
```

Как мне создать объект с помощью созданного класса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В ошибке сказано:

> non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

Другими словами: вы используете нестатическую переменную `this` внутри статического контекста метода `main`.

Вы можете возразить, что явно Вы данную переменную нигде не указывали.
И да, в Вашем коде её нет.

Данную переменную Вы использовали неявно, когда создавали объект `Bits`.
Фактически он ругается на использование `this.Bits`.

`this.Bits` - именно так, потому что данный вложенный класс находится в нестатическом контексте и принадлежит ему.

Вложенные классы подчиняются тем же правилам, что и другие ресурсы класса.
В Вашем случае, например, объект `Bits` должен иметь доступ к контексту объекта `Main`.
Но его(экземпляра объекта `Main`) нет, как и нет его контекста, а следовательно и нет доступа к классу `Bits`.
Именно поэтому и возникает ошибка.

Отсюда два выхода:

1. Создайте объект `Bits` в контексте нового объекта `Main`:

```java
    new Main().new Bits(128, d, d1);
```

2. Объявите вложенный класс в статическом контексте. Для этого достаточно просто добавить модификатор `static` перед объявлением вложенного класса

```java
    static class Bits {
        // ...
    }
```

Ну и добавлю еще третий вариант:

3. Вы можете не использовать вложенные классы, если они Вам не нужны в явном виде.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вы очень помогли)