# Ошибка при наследовании класса

Tags: java, наследование

**Помогите исправить ошибку **

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IND_LAB_3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
        Scanner con_in = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean cor_input = false;

        System.out.println("Туристическая или санаторная стоимость дороги ");
        while (!cor_input) {
            if (ticket.setPlan(con_in.nextLine())) {
                cor_input = true;
            }
        }

        cor_input = false;
        System.out.println("Сложность ");
        while (!cor_input) {
            if (ticket.setKategory(con_in.nextLine())) {
                cor_input = true;
            }
        }
        Touristic touristic = new Touristic();
        cor_input = false;
        System.out.println("Место");
        while (!cor_input) {
            if (ticket.setPlace(con_in.nextLine())) {
                cor_input = true;
            }
        }
        cor_input = false;
        System.out.println("Продолжительность");
        while (!cor_input) {
            if (ticket.setDate(con_in.nextInt())) {
                cor_input = true;
            }
        }
        cor_input = false;

        System.out.println("Стоимость питания");
        while (!cor_input) {
            if (ticket.setCashFood(con_in.nextInt())) {
                cor_input = true;
            }
        }
        cor_input = false;
        System.out.println("Стоимость проживания");
        while (!cor_input) {
            if (ticket.setCashRest(con_in.nextInt())) {
                cor_input = true;
            }
        }
        cor_input = false;
        ticket.Display();
    }

    public class Ticket {
        String SPR = null;
        private String placeTicket;
        private double cashOfPlace;
        private String plan;
        private int date;
        private int CashFood;
        private int CashRest;
        private int TotalPrice;
        private double summ;
        private double SRsum;
        private double planSanat;
        private double planTouri;
        String kategory;

        public Ticket() {
            Priceset();
        }
        public Ticket(String placeTicket, int date, double cashOfPlace, int CashFood, int CashRest) {
            this.placeTicket = placeTicket;
            this.date = date;
            this.cashOfPlace = cashOfPlace;
            this.CashFood = CashFood;
            this.CashRest = CashRest;
            Priceset();
        }
        private void Priceset() {
            planSanat = 1.5;
            planTouri = 3.1;
        }
        public void Display() {
            System.out.println("Суммарная стоимость всего тура " + (getSumm() + "₽"));
            System.out.println("Ср стоимость дня " + getSRsum() + "₽");
        }
        public String getPlan() {
            return plan;
        }
        public String getPlace() {
            return placeTicket;
        }
        public int getdate() {
            return date;
        }
        public int getCashFood() {
            return CashFood;
        }
        public int getCashRest() {
            return CashRest;
        }
        public double getPricePlace() {

            if (this.plan.equals("Туристическая")) {

                return planTouri * cashOfPlace;
            } else {
                if (this.plan.equals("Санаторная")) {
                    return planSanat * cashOfPlace;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
        public double getSumm() {
            return getPricePlace() + getdate() * (getCashFood() + getCashRest());
        }
        public double getSRsum() {
            return (getSumm() / 2) / getdate();
        }

        public String getSPR() {
            return SPR;
        }
        public String getKategory(){
            return kategory;
        }
        public boolean setKategory(String kategory){
                if(kategory.equals("Легкая")||kategory.equals("Средняя")||kategory.equals("Высокая")){
                    this.kategory = kategory;
                    return true;

                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Неверное написание сложности");
                    return false;
                }
        }

        public boolean setPlan(String plan) {
            if (plan.equals("Туристическая") || plan.equals("Санаторная")) {
                this.plan = plan;
                return true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Неверный план");
                return false;
            }
        }

        public boolean setPlace(String placeTicket) {
            switch (placeTicket) {
                case ("Анапа"):
                    cashOfPlace = 20000;
                    this.placeTicket = placeTicket;
                    return true;
                case ("Геленджик"):
                    cashOfPlace = 21000;
                    this.placeTicket = placeTicket;
                    return true;
                case ("Новороссийск"): {
                    cashOfPlace = 24000;
                    this.placeTicket = placeTicket;
                    return true;
                }
                default: {
                    System.out.println("Неверное место назначения");
                    return false;

                }
            }
        }

        public boolean setDate(int date) {
            if (date > 0) {
                this.date = date;
                return true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Неверное значение даты");
                return false;
            }

        }

        public boolean setCashFood(int CashFood) {
            if (CashFood > 0) {
                this.CashFood = CashFood;
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public boolean setCashRest(int CashRest) {
            if (CashRest > 0) {
                this.CashRest = CashRest;
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public boolean setSPR(String SPR) {
            if (SPR.equals("Да") || SPR.equals("Нет")) {
                this.SPR = SPR;
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    class Touristic extends Ticket{
        public Touristic(String kat){
            switch (kategory) {
                case ("Легкая"):
                     SPR = "Нет";
                case ("Средняя"):
                    SPR = "Нет";
                case ("Высокая"):
                    SPR = "Да";
                default: System.out.println("Неверное написание сложности");
            }
            this.SPR = SPR;
        }
        @Override
        public void Display() {
            System.out.println("Сложность " + (getKategory()));
            System.out.println("Необходимость справки от врача " + (getSPR()));
        }
    }
}
```

ОШИБКА
В 5 СТРОЧКЕ И 23
java: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

Хотел сделать проверку ввода в main и после в наследованном классе сложность проверялась через Switch с возращением значения spr (необходимость наличия справки) в основной класс Ticket или с выводом через Touristic.display сторки

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка “non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context” при попытке создания объекта вложенного класса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1211269/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-non-static-variable-this-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8)

Answer (score 0):

Удалите весь код и скопируйте отсюда заново. У вас проблема со скобками.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IND_LAB_3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
        Scanner con_in = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean cor_input = false;

        System.out.println("Туристическая или санаторная стоимость дороги ");
        while (!cor_input) {
            if (ticket.setPlan(con_in.nextLine())) {
                cor_input = true;
            }
        }

        cor_input = false;
        System.out.println("Сложность ");
        while (!cor_input) {
            if (ticket.setKategory(con_in.nextLine())) {
                cor_input = true;
            }
        }
        Touristic touristic = new Touristic();
        cor_input = false;
        System.out.println("Место");
        while (!cor_input) {
            if (ticket.setPlace(con_in.nextLine())) {
                cor_input = true;
            }
        }
        cor_input = false;
        System.out.println("Продолжительность");
        while (!cor_input) {
            if (ticket.setDate(con_in.nextInt())) {
                cor_input = true;
            }
        }
        cor_input = false;

        System.out.println("Стоимость питания");
        while (!cor_input) {
            if (ticket.setCashFood(con_in.nextInt())) {
                cor_input = true;
            }
        }
        cor_input = false;
        System.out.println("Стоимость проживания");
        while (!cor_input) {
            if (ticket.setCashRest(con_in.nextInt())) {
                cor_input = true;
            }
        }
        cor_input = false;
        ticket.Display();
    }
}


public class Ticket {

    String SPR = null;
    private String placeTicket;
    private double cashOfPlace;
    private String plan;
    private int date;
    private int CashFood;
    private int CashRest;
    private int TotalPrice;
    private double summ;
    private double SRsum;
    private double planSanat;
    private double planTouri;
    String kategory;

    public Ticket() {
        Priceset();
    }

    public Ticket(String placeTicket, int date, double cashOfPlace, int CashFood, int CashRest) {
        this.placeTicket = placeTicket;
        this.date = date;
        this.cashOfPlace = cashOfPlace;
        this.CashFood = CashFood;
        this.CashRest = CashRest;
        Priceset();
    }

    private void Priceset() {
        planSanat = 1.5;
        planTouri = 3.1;
    }

    public void Display() {
        System.out.println("Суммарная стоимость всего тура " + (getSumm() + "₽"));
        System.out.println("Ср стоимость дня " + getSRsum() + "₽");
    }

    public String getPlan() {
        return plan;
    }

    public String getPlace() {
        return placeTicket;
    }

    public int getdate() {
        return date;
    }

    public int getCashFood() {
        return CashFood;
    }

    public int getCashRest() {
        return CashRest;
    }

    public double getPricePlace() {

        if (this.plan.equals("Туристическая")) {

            return planTouri * cashOfPlace;
        } else {
            if (this.plan.equals("Санаторная")) {
                return planSanat * cashOfPlace;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public double getSumm() {
        return getPricePlace() + getdate() * (getCashFood() + getCashRest());
    }

    public double getSRsum() {
        return (getSumm() / 2) / getdate();
    }

    public String getSPR() {
        return SPR;
    }

    public String getKategory() {
        return kategory;
    }

    public boolean setKategory(String kategory) {
        if (kategory.equals("Легкая") || kategory.equals("Средняя") || kategory.equals("Высокая")) {
            this.kategory = kategory;
            return true;

        } else {
            System.out.println("Неверное написание сложности");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean setPlan(String plan) {
        if (plan.equals("Туристическая") || plan.equals("Санаторная")) {
            this.plan = plan;
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Неверный план");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean setPlace(String placeTicket) {
        switch (placeTicket) {
            case ("Анапа"):
                cashOfPlace = 20000;
                this.placeTicket = placeTicket;
                return true;
            case ("Геленджик"):
                cashOfPlace = 21000;
                this.placeTicket = placeTicket;
                return true;
            case ("Новороссийск"): {
                cashOfPlace = 24000;
                this.placeTicket = placeTicket;
                return true;
            }
            default: {
                System.out.println("Неверное место назначения");
                return false;

            }
        }
    }

    public boolean setDate(int date) {
        if (date > 0) {
            this.date = date;
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Неверное значение даты");
            return false;
        }

    }

    public boolean setCashFood(int CashFood) {
        if (CashFood > 0) {
            this.CashFood = CashFood;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean setCashRest(int CashRest) {
        if (CashRest > 0) {
            this.CashRest = CashRest;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean setSPR(String SPR) {
        if (SPR.equals("Да") || SPR.equals("Нет")) {
            this.SPR = SPR;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}


public class Touristic extends Ticket {

    public Touristic() {
        switch (kategory) {
            case ("Легкая"):
            case ("Средняя"):
                SPR = "Нет";
                break;
            case ("Высокая"):
                SPR = "Да";
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Неверное написание сложности");
        }
        //this.SPR = SPR;
    }

    @Override
    public void Display() {
        System.out.println("Сложность " + (getKategory()));
        System.out.println("Необходимость справки от врача " + (getSPR()));
    }
}
```

Я изменил конструктор класса Touristic, чтобы он не принимал переменных, которых не использует, а также закомментровал бессмысленное присвоение самому себе для переменной SPR в том же конструкторе, плюс там же проставил брейк для свитч - кейс (советую обратить на это внимание).

А вообще этот код - полный треш)) если не понимаете почему - пишите

Comment: Разве там где-то ошибка в скобках? Просто классы Ticket и Touristic были внутренними для класса IND_LAB_3. Вроде если их сделать статическими, то код стал бы рабочим (не считая вызова конструктора без параметров для Touristic).

Comment: @Byb возможно, здесь в общем полотне разобрать сложно, к тому же непонятно, с какой радости они вдруг внутренние?